How to obtain the Hamiltonian of the Magnon through the Hamiltonian of the electron
Suppose I already have the Hamiltonian with the atomic basis for the electron in a certain crystal structure. As usual, the atomic basis is not orthogonal, which means this Hamiltonian consists of two matrice. One is the Kohn-Sham matrix; while, the other one is the overlap matrix.
Is it possible to use this Kohn-Sham matrix and the overlap matrix to obtain the Hamiltonian for the magnon in this crystal structure through the Bogoliubov transformation?
Is there any literature or textbook explaining this procedure; particularly, for the case that the basis of the electron Hamiltonian is not orthorgonal?
Would anyone please give me some suggestions/comments/hints?
Thank you in advance.
